# Monitoring disk usage of a pvc in grafana

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, monitoring

I want to monitor the disk usage% of a specific filesystem in a pod (in grafana).
I was wondering if there’s a Prometheus query I can use to do so.

Comment: Jay by "a specific filesystem" do you mean a specific volume mounted to your pod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To monitor PVC, disk usage %, you can use something like this

```js
100 - (kubelet_volume_stats_available_bytes / kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes) * 100
```

To monitor file system, disk usage %, you can use something like this

```js
100 - (node_filesystem_avail_bytes / node_filesystem_size_bytes * 100)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using `100 * sum(kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes{persistentvolumeclaim=~”name.*”}) by (persistentvolumeclaim) / sum(kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes) by (persistentvolumeclaim)`

Comment: The problem is that this produces more timeseries than necessary. Needs to take into account the PVC name

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the persistent volume claim name, to avoid having separate timeseries coming from different instances

```
100 * (sum by (persistentvolumeclaim) (kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes)) 
    / (sum by (persistentvolumeclaim) (kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes))
```